# With an accordion menu, how can I ensure opening a menu closes its siblings?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a mockup here

http://jsfiddle.net/jmLVb/

When I click

Menu2 -> Sub1

And then subsequently click Sub2 I would like Sub1 to close.  Similarly if I click

Menu2 -> Sub1 -> Blah1

And then subsequently click Blah2 I would like Blah1 to close. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/wxXav/